# How to tell if a Python program is working without having to wait for it to finish?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, xlwings

Here is my code:

```
import xlwings as xw
import datetime as dt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import threading
import time

#connect to workbook
wb = xw.Book(r'C:\Users\Ryan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\constituents.xlsx')
sht = wb.sheets['constituents']

#store data in np array, pass to Pandas
a = sht.range('A2:C1760').options(np.array).value
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df = df.rename(index=str, columns={0: "tickers", 1: "start_dates", 2: "end_dates"})

#initialize variables
start_quarter = 0
start_year = 0
fiscal_dates = []
s1 = pd.date_range(start='1/1/1964', end='12/31/2018', freq='B')
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=np.ndarray(shape=(len(s1),500), dtype=str), index=s1)

#create list of fiscal quarters
def fiscal_quarters(start_year):
    year_count = start_year - 1
    quarter_count = 1
    for n in range(2019 - start_year):
        year_count += 1
        for i in range(1,5):
            fiscal_dates.append(str(quarter_count) + 'Q'+ str(year_count)[-2:])
            quarter_count += 1
        quarter_count = 1 

#iterate over list of tickers to create self-named spreadsheets
def populate_worksheets():
    for n in range(len(fiscal_dates)):
        wb.sheets.add(name=fiscal_dates[n])

#populate df2 with appropriate tickers
def populate_tickers():
    count = 0
    for n in range(len(s1)):
        for i in range(len(df['tickers'])):
            if df.loc[str(i), 'start_dates'] <= s1[n] and df.loc[str(i), 'end_dates'] > s1[n]:
                count += 1
                df2.loc[str(s1[n]), str(count)] = df.loc[str(i), 'tickers']
        count = 0

#run populate_tickers function with status updates
def pt_thread():
    t = threading.Thread(target=populate_tickers)
    c = 0
    t.start()
    while (t.is_alive()):
        time.sleep(5)
        count += 5
        print("Working... " + str(c) + 's')
```

First, I run `fiscal_quarters(1964)` in the Python Shell, then `pt_thread()`, which appears to be particularly resource intensive. It's been running for over a half hour for this point on my (admittedly slow) laptop. However, without waiting for it to finish running, is there any way to be able to see whether it's working as intended? Or at all? It's still printing "Working..." to the shell which I suppose is a good sign, but I'd like to start troubleshooting if something's wrong rather than waiting an indefinite amount of time before giving up on it.

For reference, the s1 Series contains ~17,500 items, while the df['tickers'] column contains ~2,000 items, so there should be somewhere in the neighborhood of 35,000,000 iterations with 4 operations each. Is this a lot, or should a modern PC be able to work through this rather quickly and my program is probably just not working?

Comment: Add some logging to your functions so that you're aware of what is going on.

Comment: Your machine should get through it in a matter of seconds. Seems like there's an issue.

Comment: Usually, if I want to make sure that things are actually running, I'll stick prints in a routine somewhere. Placing prints wherever and just seeing if they print is usually a good option. Once toy know things are running fine, it's not an issue to keep checking unless you're making large, breaking changes.

Comment: Second last line, `count += 5` is incorrect. Also, most of this code is dead, or you're not showing us the whole thing. Either way, as others have said, just add a few print statements to inspect your progress.

Comment: Why are you using a thread?

Comment: If you want to give logging a go : [Logging HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) - but printing is probably easiest.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running loops that are taking a long time and want to see what is going on you could use `tqdm`. It gives iterations per second and estimated time remaining. Here is a quick example:

```
from tqdm import tqdm

def sim(sims):
    x = 0
    pb = tqdm(total=sims, initial=x)
    while x < sims:
        x+=1
        pb.update(1)
    pb.close()
sim(5000000)
```